# WP: is it ok to modify is_front_page() and is_home() functions

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've divided my website to women and men displays, and now I'm worried about the `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` functions.

Before this change I only had `www.site.com` to be the front page, now I also have `www.site.com/men` and `www.site.com/women`, and I want them to be recognized as front pages as well.

I thought about making a new class `My_Query extends WP_Query` and override these functions.

Is this a bad idea? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to implement a `class` which is inherited from `WP_Query`, but I believe you should still support the old functionality for the case when you need it, even if you do not see such a scenario in this moment. You should have something like this:

```
class My_Query extends WP_Query {
    //...
    public function is_home($default = true) {
        if ($default) {
            return parent::is_home();
        } else {
            //Implement your custom case
        }
    }

    public function is_front_page($default = true) {
        if ($default) {
            return parent::is_front_page();
        } else {
            //Implement your custom case
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

You can have a `false` for `$default` as default if it suits your needs better. This approach would be compatible with future Wordpress versions as well, at least when you use it in default fashion.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to know if there is any alternative way recommended. Maybe a hook? But I guess this is the only way..

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan, this is a neat and elegant way. You had a pretty good idea from the start, I just helped it to take shape. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it.